# Reverse two block of elements inside a tensor using TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, tensor

Suppose I have a rank two tensor(a matrix) of the size [batch, D], and I want to exchange the position of first d columns of elements with D-d column elements. How could I do this efficiently in TensorFlow?
 Example: A matrix of size [4,4], and I want to exchange the position of first d=2 columns of elements with the block of columns left.

Input:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

Output:

```
3 4 1 2
3 4 1 2
3 4 1 2
3 4 1 2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your matrix is `A` then `tf.concat((A[:,d:], A[:,:d]), axis=1)` should give you what you want. I'm not aware of any straightforward way to make it any more efficient but I wouldn't worry about it unless it's a bottleneck in your model.

**Update:** if `d << D` and you only need to perform the operation once then the following may be faster due to reducing copy overheads (but also use more memory)

```
# allocate D + d columns
A = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((batch, D + d)))

# set A[:,:D] to initial value

# copy first d columns to the the last d columns
A = A[:,-d:].assign(A[:,:d])
# use slicing to ignore the first d columns
A = A[:,d:]
```

Comment: Hi Ed Bording, thanks for answering. From my previous experience, I found tf.concat is a very slow operation. Since the matrix is large and this operation appears a lot in the program. So I prefer to avoid tf.concat.

Comment: I've added a trick you might be able to use above but if you need to do this transformation repeatedly then it probably won't help. Without knowing what exactly you need this for I can't suggest much else. There is a chance you could make things more efficient by writing a custom op kernel - particularly if you don't need to do much to the tensor after this operation - but of course this is a lot of work.